# print consulta mysql

Tags: php

Cómo puedo imprimir la consulta mysql que se está ejecutando en una página. Tengo una consulta de búsqueda que no arroja los resultados esperados, quiero que se imprima para saber si está bien construida. es posible hacerlo?? ya intenté con print_r $_GET y se imprimen las variables pero no la consulta

Comment: como realizas la consulta?

Comment: la query en si como se realiza? pdo, msqli, query builder de un framework?

Comment: ah ok. creo que es mysqli. estoy aprendiendo a modificar un wordpress 2.0 muy básico. $wpdb

Comment: si armas la query con $wpdb agrega esa parte del código en la pregunta y dejamos la respuesta para otros que  puedan tener la misma inquietud

Comment: el código es parte de una función más larga. El fragmento donde hace las querys de búsqueda es el que pongo a continuación. if (!$q['sentence']) {$s_array = explode(' ',$q['tema']);  $q['search_terms'] = $s_array; $search .= '((post_tema LIKE \''.$n.$s_array[0].$n.'\') )'; for ( $i = 1; $i < count($s_array); $i = $i + 1) { $search .= ' AND ((post_tema LIKE \''.$n.$s_array[$i].$n.'\') )';
 }$search .= ' OR (post_tema LIKE \''.$n.$q['tema'].$n.'\') ';
 $search .= ')'; } else { $search = ' AND ((post_tema LIKE \''.$n.$q['s'].$n.'\') )';}  aunque funciona no permite concatenar busquedas

Comment: no nos entendemos, ese código que veo es el que pusiste en la otra pregunta es el que arma la consulta, si la arma mal es ambito de la otra pregunta. en este caso si queres saber como queda haces un echo $search, por otro lado si la pregunta actual es "como saber la ultima consulta SQL ejecutada por wpdb" ahi es necesario saber como se realiza la consulta $wpdb->prepare, $wpdb->execute o si es un simple $wpdb->query()

Comment: Ok. encontré la consulta y probable problema. Consulta: $request = " SELECT $distinct * FROM $wpdb->posts $join WHERE 1=1".$where." ORDER BY " . $orderby . " $limits"; hago un
echo $request; e imprime la consulta: SELECT DISTINCT * FROM posts WHERE 1=1 AND post_tema LIKE '%puebla%' AND post_tema LIKE '%puebla%' AND post_date_gmt <= '2018-04-08 03:34:59' AND (post_status = "publish") GROUP BY posts.ID ORDER BY post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 10  Resulta que está repetido dos veces "AND post_tema like %puebla%, que es la consulta del $search = ' AND (post_tema LIKE \''. $n. $lhtema. $n. '\')';